# How to add Event Receiver for subsites

Tags: sharepoint

I have sub sites of departments and under each department site I have sub sites of programs. I want to add an event receiver that should invoke when a sub site of department is created. so that I can add the name of that program and department is list.

Comment: Did you check for opions? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

MOSS 2007 : SharePoint does not have event handling for Site Creation.

SP 2010 : Take a look at Site [WebProvisioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.webprovisioned.aspx) and [WebAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.webadding.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 0):

Do you control what kinds of sites are created?
If so you could add a feature to the sitedefinitions which can write to your list in its feature activated method of the feature receiver.